# sending a docx but detected as application/x-tika-ooxml instead of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, apache-tika, file-extension

I am using tika to detect media file types (extensions), but whenever I send a docx, doc, xls, they are detected as "application/x-tika-ooxml". here is my method for determining fileExtensions

```
private static String determineFileExtension(String mimeType) {
        String fileExtension = "";
        if (mimeType != null) {
            if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
                fileExtension = ".pdf";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
                fileExtension = ".xls";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")) {
                fileExtension = ".xlsx";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")) {
                fileExtension = ".jpg";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("video/mpeg")) {
                fileExtension = ".mpeg";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("video/mp4")) {
                fileExtension = ".mp4";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/x-tika-ooxml")) {
                fileExtension = ".xlsx";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/x-tika-msoffice")) {
                fileExtension = ".xls";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain")) {
                fileExtension = ".txt";
            } else if (mimeType
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")) {
                fileExtension = ".docx";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")) {
                fileExtension = ".ppt";
            } else if (mimeType
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")) {
                fileExtension = ".pptx";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("video/avi")) {
                fileExtension = ".avi";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/x-zip-compressed")) {
                fileExtension = ".zip";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("image/png")) {
                fileExtension = ".png";
            } else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/msword")) {
                fileExtension = ".doc";
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Unknown mimeType  " + mimeType);
            }
        }
        return fileExtension;
    }
```

I tried changing the file extension for "application/x-tika-ooxml"

```
} else if (mimeType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/x-tika-ooxml")) {
                fileExtension = ".xlsx";
```

to docx, doc, however, I still got the same results

I am using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

other file formats, such as .pdf .xml .mp4 .jpeg, .jpg .mp3 are working

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika to do the detection? And why aren't you asking Tika for the file extension yourself?

Comment: public final class FileTypeUtils {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileTypeUtils.class);
 
 private FileTypeUtils() {
 }

 public static String getFileType(File inputFile) throws Exception {

  final Tika tika = new Tika();
  try {
   return tika.detect(inputFile);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   LOGGER.error("*** getFileTypeViaTika2 - Error message: " + e.getMessage());
   LOGGER.error("*** getFileTypeViaTika2 - Error trace"+e);
   throw new Exception("File type unknown");
  }
  
 }

Comment: If you want container-aware detection (as you'd need to detect the OOXML subtype) then you need to include the Tika office parsers jar as well

Comment: Thanks a lot; I am now able to send more file types. I added the parsers as you advised